# Problems with UTF8 to display data (strange characters)

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Im using Laravel Framework to retrieve some data from my database to my views, so I work with this query to get all records from the `products` table

```
$data = Product::all();
```

And I send those data from controller to the view in this way

```
return view('view', compact('data'));
```

But at the moment of displaying data with accents, these are not correclty formmated, showing this

> "name": "¤and£",

What I have do at this point (without any success)

- My database has `utf8mb4`
- My tables are `utf8mb4` both for character set and collate
- My views have `<meta charset="utf-8" />`
- I have saved my files as `utf8 without/with` BOM

Note

When I run a simple query like this into my mysql CLI

```
SELECT * FROM products;
```

I receive the correct value

> ñandú

So what can I do?

> Event I have tried this same data through a pure PHP script using PDO
>   and the data returned is correct I mean words show in a correct
>   way; so I don't know what else can change or configure in Laravel to
>   achieve it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language or platform are u using. But the solution lies in telling your view that the data is "UTF-8" formatted. Similar thing happens in my code in java when I miss telling my rest controller that it produces "UTF-8" data

Comment: sorry by that Iam using Laravel Framework (it uses PHP as language)